# Managing Python Environments With Conda

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, conda

I created two environments with Anaconda to be able to switch back and forth between Python 27 and Python 35 according to my needs.  I was successful in setting up those environments but no matter which environment I active and then check the version it still always says Python 3.5.1.  I've attached an image of this issue in the Powershell.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0QMi.png)

Comment: Did you created the `python2` environment with `conda create -n python2 python=2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activating environments from within PowerShell is not supported (yet), see https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626.

Use the normal CMD shell instead.